# stm32f0 sht35 i2c communication failure

Tags: sensor, stm32, i2c

I need to read temparature and rh values from sht35 sensor. here is the [datasheet](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/682/Sensirion_Humidity_Sensors_SHT3x_Datasheet_digital-1368032.pdf)

I am using stm32f0 and I have 2 different sensor. problem keep occurs with both sensor. Address pin connected to the ground so i2c address must be 0x44 but my code stucks at the while loop below. I am using keil, and cubemx to generate configurations. I watch sda and scl lines with a scope and everything looks right.what could be the possible problem of failure? ps: I tried checking out of the while loop too, nothing changed.

```
while(HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1, 0x44, 2, 100) != HAL_OK);
```

my i2c init function is here

```
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 1 */
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.Timing = 0x2000090E;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2Masks = I2C_OA2_NOMASK;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Analogue filter 
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigAnalogFilter(&hi2c1, I2C_ANALOGFILTER_ENABLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Digital filter 
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigDigitalFilter(&hi2c1, 0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 2 */

}
```

edit:

```
HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1, 0x44, 2, 100)
```

waits for an ACK signal from i2c bus, I can't see any ACK on scope too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong address. 0x44 in 7-bit notation is used in datasheet, so in 8-bit notation used by STM32 it should be 0x88.

Comment: of course, that's documented in hal library. thanks, worked.